# How to deploy frascati app in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, war

I've done the hello-world on frascati platfrom and I've run it from cmd.

I've also done the hello-world for Google App Engine, deployed it and run it.

But how can I deploy a frascati app in GAE?

How do I pack the whole frascati platform with the app as a WAR?

Comment: http://ow2-frascati.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=frascati&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2Ffrascati-in-the-cloud%2FGoogle+App+Engine%2FREADME.txt

$ mvn clean install

$ cp jars/* target/frascati-gae-1.5-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/

$ /appengine-java-sdk-1.5.4/bin/appcfg.sh update target/frascati-gae-1.5-SNAPSHOT

Comment: ok, that's the point @Paul_C, I've been going crazy with that for the last two days. Still dont understand what to do with that. mvn install of what? I could not download that code from any repository so I ended up copying it by hand. Still I do mvn install on that pom and get ERRORS. Ultimately, what will that download? a whole frascati modified for GAE?  Where does my App go? And how do I get the final WAR?

Comment: Fraid I don't use the java side, but this line "$ /appengine-java-sdk-1.5.4/bin/appcfg.sh update target/frascati-gae-1.5-SNAPSHOT" is the command that's uploading the application to the server. And presumably target then contains now only your hello world app but the updated version generated in line two. Is that how you have it arranged? Can't help much more I'm afraid.

Comment: yeah, thats the command for uploading the app to GAE, but I thought it meant uploading frascati. What do you mean "the updated version generated in line two"?

Comment: I think line two is where your existing GAE app (target) gets updated with the jars you need to deploy it, then line 3 deploys the updated app.

Comment: true, but still dont know where my helloworld code goes inside the frascati app. Remember frascati is a platform to deploy and run SCA apps. The other thing I still dont know is how where to do that mvn install and how to get the code for that websvn. Know what I mean? Thanks for you time btw! :)